# Is there a way to make a function call within a where construct?

Tags: function, fortran, where-clause, subroutine

I would like to do something like:

```
Real a(10)
Real b(10)

! define a and b, then

where (a<b)
  a = f1(a,b)
elsewhere
  a = f2(a,b)
endwhere

function f1(a,b)
! somehow or another operates only where a < b
end function f1

function f2(a,b)
! somehow or another operates only where a>=b
end function f2
```

I guess I could do something like

```
a = f1(a,b)
a = f2(a,b)

function f1(a,b)
where (a<b) ...
end function f1

function f2(a,b)
where (a>=b) ...
end function f2
```

but I thought the way I am trying to puzzle out would be nice to have in some ways.  Is there a way to do this?

In response to some comments, I want to operate on `a` by calling already defined functions that has too many lines of code to fit nicely here.  I can't discuss the functions, but let's say, for instance that they rely on some kind of convergence loop:

```
function f1(a,b)

real a(10), b(10)
real f1(10)

real tmp(10), conv

real tol = 1.e-5
tmp = a
f1 = sin(b*a)
conv = max(abs(f1-tmp))

while (conv > tol)
  tmp = f1
  f1 = sin(b*tmp)
  conv = max(abs(f1-tmp))
endwhile

return

end function
```

And there are ways to improve this and the math might be such that it won't converge etc. etc., but this is an example that gets at what I am talking about.  The thing is, I want it to operate only on the domain defined by the where construct.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for alternative ways to do the same thing?

Comment: When you try what you'd like to do, what happens?  Is your concern that the functions are evaluated for all values of `a` and `b`, or something else?

Comment: @francescalus  Yes, I want to make sure the functions operate only on the domains defined by the where expressions.

Comment: @VladimirF  OK, well, that's the answer then, I guess.  But I'll wait for what HPM says, though.  Seems like he might have another idea about this?

Comment: Actually my comment is wrong and francescalus is correct. I did think about elemental functions but somehow mixed it up. I wouldn't be so ashamed if I didn't teach WHERE today at work. But I didn't think about it here fo that long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where `f1` and `f2` are nonelemental functions these functions are evaluated based on all elements of the argument arrays.

However, for an elemental function `f1` or `f2` only those elements of `a` and `b` matching a true mask will be processed (elementally).

Looking at your example function, an elemental function wouldn't be suitable, so you'll have to use an alternative approach.   If you can phrase the function with a `where` construct wrapping the whole thing, though, you may be in luck with elementals.